# I can't pass object between two components (class component to functional component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue about pass an object from class component to functional component. In class component I get an object from some API, at this point all it's ok, but when I try to pass the object at the functional component is showing like ***undefined*** when I initialize a value (with hooks)

example:

```
const objectRecivedFromApi = [{name:"Jhon", age:25}, {name:"George", age:29}, {name:"Samantha", age:30}]

class ParentComponent extends Component { 
 state={
   allData: []
 }

 componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
            allData: [...objectRecivedFromApi]
        });
 }

 render(){
   const {allData} = this.state

  return(
     <ChildComponent allData={allData} />
   )
  }
}
```

ChildComponent

```
const ChildComponent = ({allData}) =>{
  const [value, setValue] = useState(allData)

  console.log(value) //It's showing undefined
  console.log(allData) //It's showing objectRecivedFromApi, why?

  return(
    <ul>
      {value.map(m=>{
       .....
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

also, I tried to use props, but it's the same case

```
function ChildComponent (props){
  const [value, setValue] = useState([...props.allData])
 .....
}
```

I'm new in react and at this point I'm a little confused, because I didn't find how can I fix this issue.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the data in both components states? if it is in the parent state, you could just use `allData` passed as `prop` in the child

Comment: Oh, because the logic that I applied inside the childComponent I set the state in different times.

Comment: This way you can end up with different state in parent and child, it's better to have one source of truth and pass a callback with setstate to the child as CertainPerformance suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `usestate` is loaded only once
For the first time, he is not getting props yet
Then he no longer updates the State again

To track the change of props you can do so

```
 useEffect(() => {
       setValue(allData);
   }, [allData])
```

I suggest you read about the life cycle of functions and Component in react

In fact, I think it is better for you to use a condition operator
Only render the component with the data in your hand

```
allData.length>0  && <ChildComponent allData={allData} />
```

Answer (score 3):

`useState`'s argument will be the initial state that gets set *the first time the component runs* - when it mounts. So

```
const ChildComponent = ({allData}) =>{
  const [value, setValue] = useState(allData)
```

will mean that the **first time** `ChildComponent` is called, `allData` will be put into the `value` stateful variable. On further renders, if `allData` changes, that won't affect `value`.

To fix it, wait to render the child until the `allData` is populated:

```
// parent
allData.length === 0 ? null : <ChildComponent allData={allData} />
```

But having the same stateful data in two different components is a bit odd. I'd suggest putting it only in *one* component, and communicate that one state between components with props. For example, to change the parent's `allData` from the child, pass down the state and the state setter as a prop:

```
<ChildComponent
  allData={allData}
  changeData={allData => this.setState({ allData })}
/>
```